# How to prepend something to the beginning of the PHP output buffer?

Tags: php, output-buffering

How do you append something to the **beginning** of the output buffer?

For example, say you have the following code:

```
ob_start();

echo '<p>Start of page.</p>';
echo '<p>Middle of page.</p>';
echo '<p>End of page</p>';
```

Before flushing the contents to the browser, how can I append something so that it appears **before** `<p>Start of page.</p>` when the page loads?

It sounds simple enough, like moving the pointer to the beginning of an array, but I couldn't find how to do it with the output buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure why a question is tagged "PHP" and "pointers" at the same time...

Comment: @H2CO3: If it's confusing, please edit it out.  I only added it because I mentioned moving the pointer in an array as an analogy.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "**prepend**".  "Append" means "to add after the end" while "prepend" means "to add before the beginning".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

** PHP 5.3 **

```
ob_start(function($output) {
    $output = '<p>Prepended</p>'.$output;
    return $output;
});

echo '<p>Start of page.</p>';
echo '<p>Middle of page.</p>';
echo '<p>End of page</p>';
```

** PHP < 5.3 **

```
function prependOutput($output) {
    $output = '<p>Appended</p>'.$output;
    return $output;
}

ob_start('prependOutput');

echo '<p>Start of page.</p>';
echo '<p>Middle of page.</p>';
echo '<p>End of page</p>';
```

Comment: I think you mean *prepend* :-)

Comment: I'm confused about how this works.  You wrote the code that does the prepending BEFORE the rest of the code, but could you please provide an example where you do the prepending with code that appears AFTER the rest of the "page" code (e.g. Start, middle, end of page)?

Comment: To rephrase: Will this execute the function `appendOutput` when `ob_start` is called, or at the very end just before the buffer is flushed? This is very important because I need the code that will be inside that function to be executed at the very end of the page, and not at the beginning.

Comment: @Programmer Yes it will execute just prior to flushing to the browser as per the documentation for reference http://www.php.net/ob_start under the parameter output_callback

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 ob_start commands and ob_end_flush() after what you want to first display then end the buffer with ob_end_flush again when you want to output the rest of the page.

eg:

```
ob_start();
ob_start();

echo '<p>Start of page.</p>';

ob_end_flush();

echo '<p>Middle of page.</p>';
echo '<p>End of page</p>';

ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the first parameter of `ob_start` (documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)), it allows you to provide a callback to be called when the buffer is **flushed** or **cleaned**. It receives a string as a parameter and outputs a string, therefore it should be easy to

```
function writeCallback($buffer)
{
    return "Added before " . $buffer;
}

ob_start("writeCallback");
```

Comment: Will this execute the function `writeCallback` when `ob_start` is called, or at the very end just before the buffer is flushed?  This is very important because I need the code that will be inside that function to be executed at the very end, and not at the beginning.

Comment: At the very end, you will have the full buffer!

Answer (score 0):

You can get content of buffer using [ob_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) function

```
ob_start();
echo "World! ";
$out1 = ob_get_contents();
echo "Hello, ".$out1;
```

Comment: This solution is easy enough to understand, but does flushing the entire contents to a variable end up using a lot more RAM, or is this not a concern?  I ask because I will be using this in quite a few pages of the site and in one of the most active areas, so I want to make sure that throwing everything into a variable doesn't suddenly double the amount of RAM being used.

Comment: If you want clean current buffer to reduce memory usage you can call to $out1 = ob_get_flush();

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting it before any output at all?  If so, then you're looking for the `auto_prepend_file` directive.  http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Correct, before any output to the browser, but could you please provide an example of how this would work?

Comment: You create a config variable in your php.ini file the specifies `auto_prepend_file=/path/to/whatever.php`.  That `whatever.php` is processed before any processing on a given page.  See the docs on the page I linked to.